# How to count the steps in a sorting took to sort the numbers in python?

Tags: python, user-interface

I have used this coding in bubble sort function for step calculation taken to do sorting

```
 def bubble(self):
    def bubble_sort ( array ) :
        swap_test = False
        for i in range ( 0, len ( array ) - 1 ):
         for j in range ( 0, len ( array ) - i - 1 ):
          if array[j] > array[j + 1] :
           array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]#elegentan way of swap

           swap_test = True
           self.textbox()
          else:
               self.sortingend()
         break
           #if swap_test == False:
        #else:
        #self.create_label()

   #print('bubble to be implemented')
    bubble_sort(self.nums)
    return self.nums
```

and for the two functions sortingend () and textbox() i have used these two codes

```
def sortingend(self):
    self.label21 = Label(self, text="Sorting Finish", width=25, height=2)
    self.label21.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=N)

def textbox(self):
    count=0
    count +=1
    self.label1 = Label(self, text="Step: %i " % count, width=25, height=2)
    self.label1.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=N)
```

but somehow this is not working and i am only getting error for count+=1 that not defined but if i put count=o in sortingend() then everytime counter will start from o.
Also when i run bubble sort on the first step only its showing that sorting finfished. how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because count isn't defined. You're saying count = count + 1. Well, what's count when you first start? You should probably use recursion, set count = 0 originally and then do textbox(self,count+1)

```
textbox(self, count):
    self.label1 = Label(self, text="Step: %i " % count, width=25, height=2)
    self.label1.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=N)


def bubble_sort ( array ) :
    count = 0
    swap_test = False
    for i in range ( 0, len ( array ) - 1 ):
     for j in range ( 0, len ( array ) - i - 1 ):
      if array[j] > array[j + 1] :
       array[j], array[j + 1] = array[j + 1], array[j]#elegentan way of swap

       swap_test = True
       self.textbox(count+1)
```

Comment: i did added count but see above every time i will call textbox() it will start from 0 so how will write it can u tell in coding lines.

Comment: ok so where do i define the initial velue of count=o in program bcoz otherwise i am getting an error.

Comment: My apologies, try it now. I added count = 0 directly under the definition of the bubble_sort function.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you write:

```
def textbox(self):
count=0
count +=1
```

This means that every time you call `textbox(self)`, you're creating `count=0`, incrementing it--and the next time you call `textbox(self)` you're doing it again.

Comment: yup i know so how do i do this if i will define outside then also it won't work....